# external links to id anchor not working - using jquery waypoints

Tags: javascript, anchor, jquery-waypoints

I am having an issue having an external page link to an id anchor on my index page. Every time I try to link to an anchor it just goes to the top of the page. It almost looks like it shows the page at the anchor for a split second but then just the top of the page.

You can take a look here .. http://jointmedias.com/clients/misfit/site/

All of the anchors work on the page but again can not link to a specific anchor from an external page. This should work http://jointmedias.com/clients/misfit/site/#p3 but it dosent.

I am using this js script for the smooth scrolling (again it works perfect on the page itself)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $("#topsec").height();
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop){
        $('#nav').css({
            position : 'fixed',
            top : '0'
        });
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
        $('#nav').removeAttr('style');  
    }
})

})


$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000,'easeInOutCubic');
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

I am too new to JS to know if this has something to do with it or not.. any help would be much appreciated. Thanks for taking a look.

Brian